# What does the downwards arrow symbol on a User mean in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I have created a user account called "MyUser" via Powershell, and the icon graphic in active directory different to that of the user test that I create via the UI.

The scripted one has a circle icon with a downwards facing arrow: [image]

The UI generated user does not has an icon that does not have the downwards facing arrow.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It means that the user object is disabled. You can right click the object and choose the "enable" option to enable it.

Comment: As additional info, the reason the programatically created user is disabled is probably because it was created without a password.

Comment: Right Click > All Tasks > Enable Account

Comment: I had a disabled user _without_ the arrow, it was very confusing. enabling and disabling again made the arrow to appear. wtf